# The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use appbar widget separately in another file. and call them but not occures error like  "The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?"

how to work arrange this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyAppBar` class should have this signature:

```dart
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => AppBar(...); // Your implementation

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

To use it:

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: MyAppBar(),
  ...
)
```

Comment: I did like the way that you told me but it occures error "The name 'AppBarTheme' is defined in the libraries 'package:eyecoin/components/1.home/appBar.dart' and 'package:flutter/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart (via package:flutter/material.dart)'. (Documentation)  Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports."   So I did import~~ as prefix and appBar: prefix.AppBarTheme() but it still errors..  @CopsOnRoad

Comment: You should change your `AppBarTheme` class name to something else because this class is also defined in the Flutter library. I've updated the code.